# View code does not work in running mode of visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When my application is in debug mode and I right click in `aspx` page and choose `View Code`, it just not works. Although it works when code is not in debug mode. It is it's default behavior or I am missing out something? If it is default behavior then why MS developer did this?
Thanks